# Difference in prefix and postfix expressions

Tags: expression, prefix, infix-notation

What is basically the difference in application of prefix and postfix expressions?
I mean what is use of prefix and postfix and which one is preferred where?

Comment: asking about prefix and postfix operator ?

Comment: Preferred is relative to who you ask and what language you use. LISP languages use prefix, Java, Python, C, etc use infix. Dunno what uses postfix

Comment: @MushahidKhan - expressions, not operators. `(+ 2 2)` vs `(2 + 2)` vs `(2 2 +)` all equal 4